# How to keep Messages chats sorted manually

Tags: macos, messages

It is possible to keep opened chats in Messages in order i sort it manually? Because it always resorts it chronologically, so it's changing all the time and it's kind of confusig to me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I was so blind or It was added in some patch, but it's in menu `View -> Sort Conversations -> Manually`.. obviously :)